# Finding the coefficient of CubicSpline interpolation

Tags: math, interpolation, data-analysis, numerical-methods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SchCy.png)

I did an interpolation and it is great. However, I want to know the equation to do find where are the concavities of the graph using second derivative

I expect a code that will show:
S(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
it can be one equation or two equations with boundaries.

Comment: The curve you've shown must use many cubic splines, each covering it's own range of x values. If you're using python, then add the python tag and post code you've written to try to answer your problem. SO is not a free code writing service and your question may attract downvotes if it looks like that is what you are using it for.